# Screen blacks and sends back after login

Tags: pi-3

I have a raspberry pi 3. It's worked fine the past couple months, but I've come across an issue.

When I try to login, the screen blacks for a moment, and then sends me back to the login screen.

NOTE: It's not that I have the wrong password. When I do type it wrong, it gives the usual error.

I've tried restarting and pulling the power supply, but nothing helps!

Comment: Your question comes up again and again. Do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

it could be that your storage (sd card?) is full. This behavior is typical for this. If it is the case try to login as root and clean up your storage. If this doesn't work you can mount your storage on a pc e.g. with a card reader and free up some space.